# In a style, how can I refer to the element on which the style is applied?

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

In a style, how can I refer to the element on which the style is applied ? For instance, in the style I define a `RenderTransform`, and I would like to add an animation on the RenderTransform :

```
    <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">

        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin"
                Value="0.5, 0.5" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                         From="1"
                                         To="1.2"
                                         AutoReverse="True"
                                         Storyboard.Target="{Binding RenderTransform}"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                         From="1"
                                         To="1.2"
                                         AutoReverse="True"
                                         Storyboard.Target="{Binding RenderTransform}"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

Of course, the code above doesn't work, because `{Binding RenderTransform}` uses the DataContext as the source. I tried to specify the `RelativeSource` with `FindAncestor` mode, but it can't find a `FrameworkElement` parent (probably because the storyboard is not part of the visual tree).

Is there a way to bind to a property of the element on which the style is applied ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Storyboard in a Style automatically targets the element to which the style is being applied  So you can just leave out the Storyboard.Target altogether.  However you will need to change your TargetProperty to navigate from the element itself rather than from the RenderTransform property.  The following therefore works for me:

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                 From="1"
                 To="1.2"
                 AutoReverse="True"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX" />
```